# ¿Qué ha pasado con el instalador de MongoDB en Google Colab?

Tags: mongodb, google-colab

Me encuentro aprendiendo un poco sobre MongoDB y hasta ahora he estado usándolo en Google Colab.

Al usarlo de esta manera en cada notebook debía usar la siguiente línea:

```
!apt install mongodb
```

Sin embargo desde hace unos días ha dejado de funcionar y muestra este mensaje:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

Así que ya no puedo seguir practicando.

He estado esperando unos días para ver si alguien mostraba luz sobre el asunto, pero o no hay solución o es un tema nada interesante, así que he decidido a preguntar por aquí.

Más allá de lo evidente (podría descargar el cliente local de mongo y seguir usando un jupiter local), me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de seguir usando mongo y colab como hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mediados de Julio, actualizaron la versión de linux en la que está basada Colab a Ubuntu 22.04

Yo lo instalé con las siguientes instrucciones en una celda:

```
!apt update
!apt install wget curl gnupg2 software-properties-common apt-transport-https ca-certificates lsb-release
!curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc|sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb-6.gpg
!echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
!apt update
!apt install mongodb-org
!mkdir /data
!mkdir /data/db
!mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

Ojalá te sirva

Comment: Pues sí! Ha funcionado! Es un tanto engorroso porque se está un rato instalando/actualizando paquetes, pero al final funciona. Para salir del paso hasta que hagan algo más "accesible" me vale (si es que alguna vez lo hacen). Muchísimas gracias, amigo!

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionó!